# Adding image to apps in android studio

Tags: android

HI guys I want to add image to my apps in android studio. I have a xml file called background.xml inside drawable folder.
These are the codes inside background.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    **android:src="xxx"** />
 </selector>
```

Inside drawable folder there is also an image called bg.jpg. So what should put for the android:src? Thanks!

Comment: try my solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/38346754/3981656

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:src="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"`

in your case,

`android:src="@drawable/bg"`

Answer (score 0):

it should be the name of file without the file extension - android:src="@drawable/bg"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:background="@drawable/bg"
```

or use

```
android:src="@drawable/bg"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:background="@drawable/bg"
```

Or use

```
android:src="@drawable/bg"
```

Use image as .png format